# How I can know who is the active user in odoo 8

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-8

I've a table `orders`, this `orders` are made by juan, and juan assignment to pedro. I want to list only the orders for pedro when Pedro logg. How I can filter this?

How  can I know who is the active user logged?

In which object, can I find this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use record rules and add following rule for sale.order model

```
[('create_uid', '=', user.id)]
```

user object keeps info about current logged user.

Comment: i solved with only "uid" in xml works but i dont know why doesnt work in python code, and im still wanted to know the var from current logged user on python code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
users = self.pool.get('res.users')
current_user = users.browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
```

current_user is the res.users object of the current user